# Python extracting number out of text using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var hours_tdate = ['22','23','<span style="color:#1d953f;">0</span>','<span style="color:#1d953f;">1</span>'];
```

This is a part of a js file. Now I want to use regex to extract the numbers from the above string, and having the output like this:

```
[22,23,0,1]
```

I have tried:

```
re.findall('var hours_tdate = \[(.*)\];', string)
```

And it gives me:

```
'22','23','<span style="color:#1d953f;">0</span>','<span style="color:#1d953f;">1</span>'
```

I don't know why it has no match when I tried:

```
re.findall('var hours_tdate = \[(\d*)\];', string)
```

Comment: first thing first :- It should be `\d+` along with word boundary..https://regex101.com/r/nS1xG6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\d+` along with word boundary to extract the numbers only

```
\b\d+\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS1xG6/1)**

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'\b\d+\b')
test_str = "var hours_tdate = ['22','23','<span style=\"color:#1d953f;\">0</span>','<span style=\"color:#1d953f;\">1</span>'];"

print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Z5O54t)**

**NOTE** :- Even if there will be digits in variable name, it won't matter as long as your format of variable is correct

Answer (score 0):

To provide another examples:

```
['>](\d+)['<]
# one of ' or >
# followed by digits
# followed by one of ' or <
```

In `Python` Code:

```
import re
rx = r"['>](\d+)['<]"
matches = [match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(rx, string)]
```

---

Or use **lookarounds** to only match what you want (no additional group needed, that is):

```
(?<=[>'])\d+(?=[<'])
```

Again, in `Python` Code:

```
import re
rx = r"(?<=[>'])\d+(?=[<'])"
matches = re.findall(rx, string)
```